# Is my site about to be SQL injected/hacked?

Tags: web-application, network, attacks, sql-injection

I'm running Opencart, an ecommerce CMS on a public website.

About a week ago I noticed a decent spike in direct traffic in Google Analytics (meaning these users input my URL directly rather than being referred organically or through social media) on a single day. The next day traffic was back to normal. This was quite strange, and I found that most of these users were from the USA and some were from France/Germany. My site services customers in another country, so this traffic struck me as odd, but I didn't think too much of it.

However, more recently a bunch of new customers have signed up under the exact same name using different email addresses and different IP addresses. There were 5 in a row, each 1-3 hours apart. Again, this is unusual - it's never happened before on this site. At the time I thought OK, maybe I'm being spammed, although site performance has been fine since this started.

What freaked me out was the most recent signup. This person set their name to "**DbLks Trackr**" and had a similar email address. I then looked at the IPs of all of these signups - this most recent one and the ones with the same name. Most are proxies, two are Ukrainian and one is American.

I'm thinking my URL has been posted on some forum or IRC and people are planning to try and take the database, which is why they're signing up.

It's not a very big ecommerce store at all so I didn't think it'd be much of a target really. I'm pretty sure my own PC isn't infected, but my Opencart version hasn't been updated in a while.

What's going on here? Is it likely they could access my database through an SQL injection or other means? Or is it likely to be harmless trolling?

UPDATE: proxy traffic is probing my site, looking at js and image files. Seems like a bot or bots looking for a vulnerability or the admin page.

Comment: Why don't you do the logical thing... and update your Opencart version to the most recent available? Surely prevention is better than... not... Also, I'd like to know the name of your store, so I know not to purchase from there, since it seems you're not concerned enough about the security of your customers payment details to keep your system up-to-date!

Comment: Trolling or probing? I don't know... I suspect only your attacker knows their true intentions, right? Why don't you ask them?

Comment: @Sebivor - there are a multitude of reasons why someone may not have updated. If recent releases of the system didn't make any improvements to security why would they?

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ In the absence of further information (such as version number, or confirmation that there have been no such improvements to security), it seems silly to indulge upon that line of reasoning. As a general rule of thumb, we should keep all software, including operating system software, server software and the hosted packages, up-to-date, as you can't be sure that vulnerabilities patched will be documented in the changelog; after all, many vulns are patched without even being known about, as demonstrated by the OpenBSD team.

Comment: @Serbivor I'm using an old version because updating it would completely change the layout of the frontend. It's not as simple as updating WP - I think I'd have to manually update all VQMod plugins too. AFAIK there's no pressing security vulnerabilities with this old version, so I don't want to update (especially without spending a few days to prepare in a dev environment). Because the site is so small I wasn't preparing for an attack which is obviously a mistake on my part. Now I'm just trying to figure out how likely one is and whether I need to update (if it would help or not).

Comment: @user16421 ... and those plugins, are they perhaps *free backdoors*?

Comment: My suggestion, as usual, is that you should spend 80% of your time sharpening your axe before you try to cut down the tree. Please [read more](https://www.getastra.com/blog/cms/opencart-security/prevent-opencart-malware-injection/), and then you'll feel the need to ask less, which will save us duplicating information for you...

Comment: @Serbivor what makes you think that? Wouldn't my site say "hacked by x script kiddie" by now? Or wouldn't my DB have been taken the instant I installed the plugin?

Comment: @Sebivor Fair enough, I'll work on updating. I'd like to keep the post up if I may in case someone has something to say about the strange signups under the same name.

Comment: Don't make the error of assuming all attacks are defacements. You run an opencart system. Your theoretical attackers likely want your customers credit card details, which means they probably don't want you to know. They want to be able to harvest credit cards for as long as possible.

Comment: @Sebivor Good point. Currently PayPal handles CC transactions off-site (it redirects to PayPal.com), an attacker would have to change this to redirect to their own phony site to capture this information right? Or would they be able to take it without changing the redirect provided they got access?

Comment: Other motivations might include cryptoransom attacks against you; perhaps your database isn't that valuable to you, and you don't mind it being stolen? You know, my grandfather (the "Ivor", Ivor Lewis as it were) would probably be telling me about some fantastic Serbian pottery or jewellery, to give me some different perspective on being called a "Serb"... God bless his soul!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72628/discussion-between-user16421-and-sebivor).

Comment: I have a few small Opencart shops online and on 4 of my five shop's this same person/script has signed up: First Name: DbLks
Last Name: Trackr
Customer Group: Default
E-Mail: dbleakstracker@hotmail.com
Telephone: 1091109110911

Comment: That's a match. When did they sign up? Have you also had other new customers sign up with proxies under the same name?

Comment: My shop's are unrelated and on different servers. But this person signed up this morning between 5:00 and 6:00 (CET, Amsterdam time zone). I also have another supicious sign up from "James Kelvin". Just happened a few minutes ago on different Opencart sites...

Comment: Thanks a bunch for that. We can confirm it's a script targeting Opencart sites then. I've had a bunch of proxy signups all under the name James Kelvin (7 in total now) as well as the DbLks one in the past 12 or so hours.

Comment: It looks like these user registrations are used to obtain the email adresses of the webshops for spoofing. I now get a lot of undelivered email bounces on the info@ mail adress of my website. I think spam mails are now sent with the email adresses obtained...

Comment: @Rolf That would make sense. I haven't noticed any bounce messages yet but I'll keep an eye out.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the title question is: maybe.

Not to come across too “jaded”, but all websites are nearly constantly in that state. Anyone who argues otherwise just isn’t being realistic :)

However, based on your thorough analysis along with some comments here, it appears that there may be some recent discovery of a new vulnerability, or perhaps a recent post on some forum has piqued peoples interest in OpenCart again.

From a quick 30 second search, it seems that OpenCart 2.2.n through 2.3.n have suffered from both SQLI and XSS vulnerabilities: https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-9599/Opencart.html

You can see a few bugs listed on that page that were updated within the last 12 months. I also saw a github repo where an OpenCart maintainer seemed very... careless (?) about some potential vulnerability.

As such, I would recommend following the sound advice of other posters here, get your site updated ASAP! Even if it means taking it offline for a few minutes.

Then, if you’re still worried about those accounts and email addresses, you can always drop them from your db!

Answer (score 1):

From your question and [Rolf's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/179085/125176), I think this is a person/system adding themselves to your database, so in the event that someone 'leaks' your DB in the future, they'll be able to verify the details.

But really. Unless you want to end up on that list, update your site.